# how to remove dynamic key from a predefined base class in typescript?

Tags: typescript

suppose I have my 3rd party base class like the following example:

```
export class Base {
    [k: string]: any;
    foo(): number;
    bar(): number;
};
```

which then I'll need to inherit from, but I dont want a dynamic key in my object, is it possible?

e.g, I want to be able to type-safely do something like:

```
class Child extends Base {
    // remove all dynamic keys
    // well dont actually delete it, just make it non-accessible from my ts-code.
    bzx(): number { return 3; }
}

const b = new Child();
b.foo() // OK;
b.bzx() // OK;
b.baz() // not allowed;
```

I have tried following the example for `FunctionProperties<T>` in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html

but it seems it failed again if `T` has `[k: string]:any`;

resolved:
so yeah, following the suggestion of the accepted answe,r in the end, I endup copying the whole d.ts of the base class, except the:
`[k: string]: any`

and make it an interface instead of a class.

so, yeah the idea, is, it goes like:

```
import { Base } from 'Base';
import { IBase } from 'my/own/custom/IBase.ts'
class Child extends (Base as (new () => IBase)){ ... }
```

well, I believe it is slightly better in actual code because mixins were involved, so it is something closer to:

```
function mix<C extends IBase>(base: Constructor<IBase>){ 
   return class extends base { .... }
}

class Child extends mix(Base){ ... }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't unfortunately get the keys in the non-dynamic part of a type. `keyof` will always return `string` for `Base`. However, we can use `Pick` to get the properties of the non-dynamic keys. If you don't mind spelling out all the keys (and I realize that is a big if) you can do the following:

```
export declare class Base {
    [k: string]: any;
    foo(): number;
    bar(): number;
};

const SafeBase = Base as (new () => Pick<Base, 'foo' | 'bar'>)
class Child extends SafeBase {
    // remove all dynamic keys
    // well dont actually delete it, just make it non-accessible from my ts-code.
    bzx(): number { return 3; }
}

const b = new Child();
b.foo() // OK;
b.bzx() // OK;
b.baz() // not allowed;
```